# Why is this statement 'There is a real number $x$ such that $x^2 < x$.' not true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Determine whether the statements are true or false.
>   There is a real number $x$ such that $x^2 < x$.

My obvious answer was the statement is true,
take e.g. $x=0.5$

But the solution says otherwise: (Discrete Mathematics with Applications)
[image]

This is strange, is the answer wrong because all I need to show is that there exists one real number for this given statement to be true.

edit: added question screenshot: part b)
[image]

Comment: If the question is what you say it is, then it seems like there's an error on the part of the author.

Comment: I suspect that there's something wonky going on with the quantifiers here. As the question stands, yes, clearly there is such a number $x$, but it looks like the solution manual somehow interpreted it as meaning "for all values $x$".

Comment: Looks strange to me. Perhaps there's a subtle distinction I don't see between "the truth value of the statement is *true*" and "the statement is *false*".

Comment: @EthanBolker There really better not be . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Agreed!

Comment: Is this one of those "read the whole question" questions?

Comment: Trying to read the mind of the author, this is how I think they see it: You can substitute any actual real number for $x$, and the sentence should be true regardless. But that's a very controversial interpretation of a sentence beginning with "there exists an $x$".

Comment: I will post the screenshot of the question but it is pretty much what is it already written..

Comment: @Arthur It's not "controversial" so much as "wrong." :P

Comment: It is quite strange, because the statement as you have given is true. Also, if it were to be proved wrong, why take a number as complicated as $2.1$? Looks like $2.1$ is being mentioned in some context in your text, otherwise he could just say $2^2 = 4 > 2$. Also, it is possible that somewhere, there are two quantifiers giving rise to two questions: one being there exists $x$ and one being for all $x$, the answers to which are true and false respectively. Please read a neighbourhood of the above paragraph in the textbook to see if something extra is mentioned, quoted etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is correctly quoted, it is terribly incorrect. It looks like a copy/paste error: the text $$\mbox{The truth value of this statement is 'True' . . . but the statement is False}$$ makes me suspect that in an earlier draft, this was *two* examples - one of the form "there exists an $x$" and one of the form "for all $x$."

Comment: phew this really got me scared for one moment.. as the arthur went pretty far to explain why the statement was false, so it was hard to think it could be a mistake. haha. thanks